# How to find value of a particular table column heading using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print the value of the column heading "Database Version" from a table in html using beautiful soup.

```
    import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

page = urllib.request.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/Harshal/Desktop/G3J_JAVA_Critical%20(Yellow)_EWA.htm").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
     if 'Database Version' in row:
         print(soup.td)
```

I dont understand the logic of how to print the cell below the database version. I can go find_next('td') 4 times to fetch it but that does not make the code dynamic.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML file to make it more clear?

Comment: <td class="sa-table-col-title">Database Version</td>

Comment: the table class is similar to many of the tables and also it does not have any table id so cannot fetch through it.